# Firebase Cloud Messaging request DeviceID without connecting to Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using ionic and [firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) to develop an app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging. Is there a way to request the device id, without connecting to firebase? I need this, because to be compliant with GDPR, users have to be able to opt out of getting Push Notifications. I want to store the information about which device is opted out in my database though, for which it would be nice to know the device id, so that users could opt in to push notifications in other ways than through my app later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The device ID that is used by FCM is generated on Google's servers. There is no way to get a device ID without the app communicating with those servers.